# While loop with not equal operation repeatedly going even after statement is true

Tags: python, while-loop

Basically, I have an input question with three choices. I want to make it so that the question repeats itself if the user inputs anything other than the three given choices. Here is my sample code:

```
choice = input("Select one option: ")
while choice.lower().strip() != "a" or choice.lower().strip() != "b" or choice.lower().strip() !="c":
  print('\n')
  if choice.lower().strip() == "a":
    print("test 1")
  elif choice.lower().strip() == "b":
    print("test 2")
  elif choice.lower().strip() == "c":
    print("test 3")
  else:
    print('Your input is not within the given choices, please try again')
    choice = input("Select one option: ")
```

Problem is, the loop repeats itself even after giving a, b, or c. It goes to its respective if statement, prints the text, and goes back to the start of the loop. I'm relatively new to Python and I would appreciate anyone's replies.

Comment: You just need to add the `break` keyword to the cases where you'd like to exit the loop - you were so close!

Comment: What does the '.lower' part of the variable do?

Comment: The subject professor for this assignment is preventing us from using the break keyword. Is there another option? Also, the lower is just there to ensure that even if they answer in upper case letter (for example, A), the program automatically changes this to lower case a so that the statement still is true.

Comment: Ok. What is the strip for? I don't see any need for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the complicated checking in the loop condition. You can use a simple variable to keep you in the loop:

```
choice = input("Select one option: ")
guessed = False
while not guessed:
  print('\n')
  if choice.lower().strip() == "a":
    print("test 1")
    guessed = True
  elif choice.lower().strip() == "b":
    print("test 2")
    guessed = True
  elif choice.lower().strip() == "c":
    print("test 3")
    guessed = True
  else:
    print('Your input is not within the given choices, please try again')
    choice = input("Select one option: ")
```

Alternatively you can use `while True` loop and the [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) keyword to end the loop after a correct answer:

```
choice = input("Select one option: ")
while True:
  print('\n')
  if choice.lower().strip() == "a":
    print("test 1")
    break
  elif choice.lower().strip() == "b":
    print("test 2")
    break
  elif choice.lower().strip() == "c":
    print("test 3")
    break
  else:
    print('Your input is not within the given choices, please try again')
    choice = input("Select one option: ")
```

Comment: Our professor is limiting what we can use and break is one thing we aren't allowed to utilize. Is there a workaround to it?

Comment: Thank you so much!